# SQlite3 header not linking

Tags: c, linux, sqlite

I tested the example program that uses sqlite and it doesn't work anymore (i tried a few months ago and it worked well). It throws a bunch of errors like :

```
undefined reference to `sqlite3_open()`
undefined reference to `sqlite3_close()`
```

You get the point, i get every single function from the sqlite api as an undefined reference. I really don't know what to do, i placed the qsqlite3.hq and qsqlite3.cppq in the same folder (even though the first time this was not necessary), sqlite3 is installed and working well (i'm using ubuntu saucy).

What to do ?

Comment: Headers don't link! object files or libraries do.Make sure those are present and in the right path.

Comment: How does your compiler call that emits these errors look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link against the sqlite3 library.

Add `-lsqlite3` to your compiler arguments.